# loop through divs inside a div

Tags: javascript, dom

I need an idea on how to start a loop where I can get the innerHTML for the 3 divs inside a div:

```
<div id="hi">
 <div> Item1 </div>
 <div> Item2 </div>
 <div> Item3 </div>
</div>
```

I need to make a function that search through the item list and see for common items. I know one way is to use `document.getElementsByTagName` but I don't need to see the innerHTML for each div.

Comment: *I don't need to see the innerHTML for each div* I thought the `innerHTML` is exactly what you want to get? Have you had a look at [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)? What have you tried so far? `document.getElementsByTagName` is a good start, what exactly are you having problems with now? Obviously we won't do your homework...

Comment: Other than pasting his assignment into the SO question box, it doesn't look like he's actually _tried_ anything.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, "see for common items" doesn't explain it well.

Comment: you want to IDENTIFY the ones with duplicate values?  Or you want to strip the extra duplicate value?  I'm confused..

Answer (score 15):

Since `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array, you can use a `for` loop for each of the elements.

```
var div = document.getElementById('hi');
var divs = div.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
  divArray.push(divs[i].innerHTML);
}
```

This will push the `innerHTML` of each of the elements into the `divArray` variable and iterate through them.

Comment: It returns a `NodeList`, not an array (it doesn't make much of a difference here though). Your code is not correct btw (have a look at `i`).

Comment: Boy, I sure rushed through that one. Thanks for looking out!